# vba-Finding a set with multiple range values

Tags: vba, excel, find

I am looking for a way to generate a Set with two given range values.

For example, in my code, I have the following :

```
Set myList = FindAll(columnValue, Sheet2.Range("ColumnName"))
Set advisorFound = myList.Offset(, -2)
```

What i would like to do is be able to FindAll with two range values such as :

```
Set myList = FindAll(columnValue, Sheet2.Range("ColumnName"), anotherColumnValue, Sheet2.Range("anotherColumnName"))
```

However, I am aware that the FindAll function is not what I am looking for since it only takes up to two parameters and the rest of the code wouldn't make sense either if I was using that (the offset wouldn't work).

My end goal would be to : get a set of rows that contain both of the range restrictions, and i would simply like to have access to a row in this set that has a minimal value in another column (compared to other rows found)

I have looked up the documentation (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx) but I can't seem to find what I am looking for. Thanks in advance, I appreciate your help :)

Comment: Why not use filter and then copy the visible to another sheet.  Then you can search that data set for your minimum.

Comment: @Scott Craner : oh thats a great and simple idea :) will try that ! I guess i was overcomplicating the problem.  Thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

you could use `AutoFilter()`:

```
With Worksheets("Sheet2") '<--| reference your data sheet
    With .Range(.Range("ColumnName"), .Range("anotherColumnName")) '<--| reference its range ranging between two named ranges
        .AutoFilter Field:=.Parent.Range("ColumnName").Column - .Columns(1).Column + 1, Criteria1:=columnValue '<--| 1st filter on first named range
        .AutoFilter Field:=.Parent.Range("anotherColumnName").Column - .Columns(1).Column + 1, Criteria1:=anothercolumnValue '<--| 2nd filter on 2nd named range
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Resize(, 1)) > 1 Then '<--| if any filtered cell then
            With Intersect(.Resize(.Rows.count - 1).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow, .Columns(1).Offset(, -2)) '<--| reference cells two columns to the left of the lower column index named range filtered ones
                Set myList = Intersect(.Find(what:=WorksheetFunction.min(.Cells), lookat:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues).EntireRow, .Parent.UsedRange) '<-- set the row "used" range with the minimum value in the referenced cells
            End With
        End If
    End With
    .AutoFilterMode = False
End With
```